# HKWorkoutSession not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, healthkit

I am using `HealthKit` in my project and I would like to declare a `HKWorkoutSession` in one of my class. I did import `<HealthKit/HealthKit.h>`, and I tried to declare it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) HKWorkoutSession *session;
```

in the `.h` file. However, I got an error at this line:

> 'HKWorkoutSessionDelegate' is unavailable: not available on iOS

I've also tried importing `<HealthKit/HKWorkoutSession.h>` and `<HealthKit/HKWorkout.h>` but none of them work.

Note that all other classes in `HealthKit` are available (like `HKHealthStore`, `HKQuery`, etc). The only thing I found unavailable is `HKWorkoutSession` and `HKWorkoutSessionDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

`HKWorkoutSession` is only available on watchOS. You need to avoid using it in code that gets compiled for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to access the `HKWorkoutSession` from the phone? The class is used by watchOS to configure the watch for accurately measuring the user's activity data.

If you're trying to start a new workout session you can do it from the phone like this:

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

var workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
workoutConfiguration.activityType = .running
workoutConfiguration.locationType = .outdoor

healthStore.startWatchApp(with: workoutConfiguration) { (success, error) in
//Some code here
}
```